# VPN接続するとVirtualBoxのVMに接続できなくなる

Tags: virtualbox

## 状況

ホスト(Win10)からVM(VirtualBox)へのSSH接続中に、ホストでVPN接続(※)するとVMとの接続が切れます。
改めてVMへssh接続しようとしても接続できません。

ホストからVM(192.168.200.101)へは、`Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter(192.168.200.1)`経由でSSH接続しています。

VMのネットワークアドレス`192.168.200.0`です。

ホストで次のスタティックルーティングを設定しています。

```
route add -p 192.168.200.0/24 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.200.1
```

【追記】
`route delete`後、改めてスタティックルーティングを設定すると、接続できるようになります。VPN接続でスタティックルーティングが無効になるようです。

VPNは`BIG-IP Edge client`です。

## 質問

VPN接続してもVMとの接続が切れないようにするには、どのようなことをすればよいのでしょうか。
　　　　　↓
【変更】
VPN接続してもスタティックルーティングが無効にならないようにするには、どのようなことをすればよいのでしょうか。

## Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapterのネットワーク設定

```
イーサネット アダプター イーサネット 4:

   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   説明. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   物理アドレス. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 0A-00-27-00-00-16
   DHCP 有効 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: いいえ
   自動構成有効. . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.200.1(優先)
   サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.0
   デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .:
   NetBIOS over TCP/IP . . . . . . . . .: 有効
```

## VM(192.168.200.101)のネットワーク設定

```
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:31:87:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.200.101/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe31:87e9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## VPN接続前後のroute printの結果

[image: VPN接続前後のroute printの結果]

## ホスト(Win10)のIP構成　※名前の情報はマスクしています。

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP 構成

   ホスト名. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: XXXXXX
   プライマリ DNS サフィックス . . . . .: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   ノード タイプ . . . . . . . . . . . .: ハイブリッド
   IP ルーティング有効 . . . . . . . . .: いいえ
   WINS プロキシ有効 . . . . . . . . . .: いいえ
   DNS サフィックス検索一覧. . . . . . .: XXXXXX

PPP アダプター _Common_WCGW-IVA-2203 - n6753242.autumn.iva.whitecloud.jp:

   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .: XXXXXX
   説明. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: _Common_WCGW-IVA-2203 - n6753242.autumn.iva.whitecloud.jp
   物理アドレス. . . . . . . . . . . . .:
   DHCP 有効 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: いいえ
   自動構成有効. . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.17.192.49(優先)
   サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.255
   デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .: 0.0.0.0
   DNS サーバー. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.20.0.58
                                          172.20.0.59
   NetBIOS over TCP/IP . . . . . . . . .: 有効

不明なアダプター VPN - VPN Client:

   メディアの状態. . . . . . . . . . . .: メディアは接続されていません
   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   説明. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: VPN Client Adapter - VPN
   物理アドレス. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 5E-9F-B6-8C-62-67
   DHCP 有効 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   自動構成有効. . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい

イーサネット アダプター イーサネット:

   メディアの状態. . . . . . . . . . . .: メディアは接続されていません
   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   説明. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
   物理アドレス. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 10-65-30-FA-D2-63
   DHCP 有効 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   自動構成有効. . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい

イーサネット アダプター イーサネット 4:

   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   説明. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   物理アドレス. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 0A-00-27-00-00-16
   DHCP 有効 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: いいえ
   自動構成有効. . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.200.1(優先)
   サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.0
   デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .:
   NetBIOS over TCP/IP . . . . . . . . .: 有効

Wireless LAN adapter ローカル エリア接続* 1:

   メディアの状態. . . . . . . . . . . .: メディアは接続されていません
   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   説明. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #5
   物理アドレス. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 9E-30-5B-F2-DD-87
   DHCP 有効 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   自動構成有効. . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい

Wireless LAN adapter ローカル エリア接続* 2:

   メディアの状態. . . . . . . . . . . .: メディアは接続されていません
   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   説明. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #6
   物理アドレス. . . . . . . . . . . . .: AE-30-5B-F2-DD-87
   DHCP 有効 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   自動構成有効. . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .: flets-east.jp
   説明. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: Qualcomm QCA61x4A 802.11ac Wireless Adapter
   物理アドレス. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 9C-30-5B-F2-DD-87
   DHCP 有効 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   自動構成有効. . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   IPv6 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 2404:7a80:94c1:2100:9026:88be:d0f:6ee3(優先)
   一時 IPv6 アドレス. . . . . . . . . .: 2404:7a80:94c1:2100:938:57ee:c038:6fdc(使用されていません)
   一時 IPv6 アドレス. . . . . . . . . .: 2404:7a80:94c1:2100:c59:95c0:afbe:57f2(優先)
   一時 IPv6 アドレス. . . . . . . . . .: 2404:7a80:94c1:2100:c019:2a00:5174:6c86(使用されていません)
   リンクローカル IPv6 アドレス. . . . .: fe80::9026:88be:d0f:6ee3%13(優先)
   IPv4 アドレス . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.1.5(優先)
   サブネット マスク . . . . . . . . . .: 255.255.255.0
   リース取得. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 2019年12月27日 01:46:36
   リースの有効期限. . . . . . . . . . .: 2019年12月29日 15:26:41
   デフォルト ゲートウェイ . . . . . . .: fe80::225:36ff:feb4:9f8d%13
   DHCP サーバー . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 362557531
   DHCPv6 クライアント DUID. . . . . . .: 00-01-00-01-22-90-2D-12-10-65-30-FA-D2-63
   DNS サーバー. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 2404:7a80:94c1:2100:225:36ff:feb4:9f8d
                                          192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over TCP/IP . . . . . . . . .: 有効
   接続固有の DNS サフィックス検索の一覧:
                                          flets-east.jp
                                          iptvf.jp

イーサネット アダプター Bluetooth ネットワーク接続 4:

   メディアの状態. . . . . . . . . . . .: メディアは接続されていません
   接続固有の DNS サフィックス . . . . .:
   説明. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #4
   物理アドレス. . . . . . . . . . . . .: 9C-30-5B-F2-DD-88
   DHCP 有効 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
   自動構成有効. . . . . . . . . . . . .: はい
```

Comment: 効果があるのかどうかは不明ですが、明示的に interface を指定してみてはどうでしょうか。`route add -p 192.168.200.0/24 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.200.1 if 22`

Comment: 古いルーティングを削除して、教えていただいたifを明示するルーティングを追加したところ接続できました。しかしながらVPNを切断して、再度接続すると、現象(SSH接続できない)が再発します。スタティックルーティングは残っています。`route delete 192.168.200.0`して再度`route add -p 192.168.200.0/24 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.200.1 if 22`を実行すると、また接続できるようになります。試しにinterfaceを明示しない方法(if 22を付けない)でもうまく行きました。VPN接続後に`route delete`を実行したあと`route add`したことにより現象が回避できたようです。いずれにしてもVPN接続中にもVMにSSH接続できるようになったので大きな前進です。metropolis さん、ありがとうございました。VPN切断後にルーティングが効かなくなる現象についても知見があればお教えください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: VPN接続前だと、`192.168.200.0/24`へのルーティングを指定しなくてもホスト(192.168.200.1)からゲスト(192.168.200.101)へはSSH接続できるはずですが、できないので`route add`で追加しているのでしょうか? (ネットワーク構成が特殊なのか気にしています)

Comment: user20098 さん、コメントありがとうございます。最初はSSH接続できていたような気がしますがありますがスタティックルーティングの実施前か記憶が定かではありません。しばらくして接続できなくなりましたので、試行錯誤でスタティックルーティングを追加したところまた接続できるようになりました。VPN接続前後に接続できない現象が再発しましたので質問しました。

Comment: Windows PowerShell に [Add-VpnConnectionRoute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/add-vpnconnectionroute?view=win10-ps) というコマンドがあって、これを利用して VPN 接続のルーティングを設定してみると良いかもしれません。`Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "VPN Connection Name" -DestinationPrefix 172.17.0.0/16 -PassThru`  この中の `"VPN Connection Name"` は [Get-VpnConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/get-vpnconnection?view=win10-ps) で調べる事ができます。

Comment: metropolis さん、コメントありがとうございます。Get-VpnConnectionで何も表示されず、 Add-VpnConnectionRoute が試せていません。

Comment: VPN 接続を行ってから Get-VpnConnection を実行していますか？

Comment: PowerShellで`Get-VpnConnection`を実行しましたが、何も表示されませんでした。Win10の機能でVPN接続しているのではなく、`BIG-IP Edge client`でVPN接続しています。そのせいで「何も表示されない」と推測しています。

Comment: なるほど、BIG-IP Edge client は Windows の VPN component を使わずに独自に処理を行っているのですね。少し調べてみると、[BIG-IP Edge Client operations guide | Chapter 3: Common approaches to configuring VPN](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K49720803#link_05) に、`Disallowing routing table changes` という項目があるので参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: `Disallowing routing table changes`を見てみました。私の技術レベルではハードルが高そうです。業務で指定された手順でVPN接続しているため思い切った試行ができない事情もあります。`BIG-IP Edge client`でVPN接続後に、`routeコマンド`で固定ルーティングを再設定することで問題が回避しようと思います。教えていただいたサイトの情報によると、ルーティング変更を検出して`BIG-IP(F5?)`が対応してくれているようです(解釈に自信なし)、いずれにしても情報ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己回答です。

## 解決方法

ルーティングを設定しなおすとSSH接続できるようになります。
- route delete
- route add

VPN接続すると、それまでのルーティングが無効化されるようです。
VPN接続後にルーティングする設定があるかもしれませんが試せていません。